# Convert downloaded LiDAR info to DEM in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, geotiff-tiff, lidar, ascii

I have downloaded LiDAR information as a .asc file and a .tif file, and even though I have tried multiple methods to convert them to a dem I am having no luck. Grass GIS says there is an invalid northpoint on the ascii data. Could someone here point me in the right direction?

Here are the two datasets: [1](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_ydLngVMnseOE9Eb241bWtFQ0JCTFpHb2J2NUV1T2h0cTNV/edit?usp=docslist_api) and [2](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_ydLngVMnseV0gyTzdmZGRsNnllbmhjN1VrYTZhMUtId0g4/edit?usp=docslist_api).

Comment: Thank you. I tried converting to grass ASCII, but that was not working. I've resigned and installed arcGIS and am now trying to figure out how to use it. Thanks

Comment: See my reply to your other recent question. I imported your ASCII file in its original format into the GIS Whitebox GAT (which I develop) with absolutely no problems. There is nothing wrong with your file.

Answer (score 5):

Given your error, my guess is that when you are importing the file to GRASS, it is expecting a GRASS ASCII raster format, which has a header that looks like this:

> north: ####.###
>
> south: ####.###
>
> east: ####.###
>
> west: ####.###
>
> rows: ####.###
>
> cols: ####.###

Instead of an ArcGIS ASCII grid, which has a header that looks like this:

> NCOLS ###
>
> NROWS ###
>
> XLLCORNER / XLLCENTER ###
>
> YLLCORNER / YLLCENTER ###
>
> CELLSIZE ###
>
> NODATA_VALUE ###

You have the later format. Notice that the ArcGIS ASCII format doesn't explicitly contain a 'North' entry, which the GRASS format import tool is looking for. So you can either change the header part of your file and import it as a GRASS file or select an import option that explicitly handles an ArcGIS ASCII grid. If you should choose to alter the ArcGIS ASCII format to a GRASS ASCII raster you can calculate the north, south, east, and west values as follows:

> north = YLLCORNER + NROWS * CELLSIZE
>
> south = YLLCORNER
>
> east = XLLCORNER + NCOLS * CELLSIZE
>
> west = XLLCORNER